# Fill table so that sum of each row is positive and sum of each column is negative

Tags: arithmetic

Can we fill the table below with  integer numbers such that the sum of each row is positive and the sum of each column is negative?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the sum of each row is positive, then the sum of all nine integers is positive. If the sum of each column is negative, then the sum of all nine integers is negative. Hence this is not possible.